# Trigger for insert is giving wrong results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building a trigger which fires whenever some data is inserted into the Sales table. When it fires, it updates the remaining amount for purchase in the Account table, subtracting it by the sale total amount in the Sales table. But the trigger is giving wrong results. Here's the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_Conta_Insert]
ON [dbo].[Sale]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

declare @IDAccount bigint
declare @SaleTotalAmount money
declare @RemainingAmount money

select @IDAccount= Inserted.ID_Account, @SaleTotalAmount = Sale.Amount, @RemainingAmount = RemainingAmount from Inserted, Account
if (@IDAccount is not null) and (@RemainingAmount - @SaleTotalAmount >= 0)      
    begin transaction
        update Account set RemainingAmount = @RemainingAmount - @SaleTotalAmount where Account.ID_Account = @IDAccount 
    commit
```

Why the trigger is updating the Account table with wrong results in the RemainingAmount column?

Comment: Your assignment query uses a cross join, it also makes the common but mistaken assumption that a trigger fires once per row, not once per statement.

Comment: What Aaron is saying is you need to get rid of the scalar variables and make your update statement set based and join inserted and Sale on the primary key.

Comment: It also seems odd that you would perform the same calculation during both an insert and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole trigger should be something like this.

```
update a set RemainingAmount = a.RemainingAmount - s.SaleTotalAmount 
from inserted i
join Account a on i.SomeKey = a.SomeKey
join Sale s on s.SomeOtherKey = a.SomeOtherKey
```

Also, do NOT put transactions in a trigger. You are asking for problems because nested transactions in sql server are a myth. I would reconsider what you are doing here in the first place. You are essentially storing a computed value via trigger. There are computed columns in sql server which would seem to be a much better fit here than a trigger.